# It is legal to exec private function in property setter which is bind to xaml object property?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Assume that I Have RadioButton in xaml.

```
//...
IsChecked="{Binding A}"
//...
```

Now somewhere in code I have:

```
private bool a; 
public bool A 
{ 
    get { return a; }
    set { a = value; foo(); }
}
```

I'am asking because when I add function `foo()` to setter then xaml preview changes look in strange way...

//
I'm not very familiar with C# so if it is not a problem in general to do something like that I will try to find other cause. So far I don't found it is legal but maybe it is obvious for every else :)

Comment: Do you mean in the designer?

Comment: Yes preview in the designer changes after rebuild (it also is visible in running app). All what I change is adding/removing function call to/from setter

Comment: What does `foo` do? How does the designer change? Calling methods in a setter is legal.

Comment: In my opinion it is legal. You should post more detail about your private method in order to understand your issue.

Comment: Table layout get narrows. `foo` is checking value of A (and other values similar to A, other RadioButtons) and editing list which is not correlated to any other code so far. 
So if it is legal then probably I missing something for now. Now I can get focus on other possibles issues.

Comment: Can you post a [sscce](http://sscce.org/) and perhaps screenshots of what you see? Bottom line, executing private methods is fully legal in property setters (there are some other rules for *Dependency Properties* but it doesn't seem that that is what you have).

Comment: Sorry for hassle, some objects ware not initialized...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `foo` is checking value of A (and other values similar to A, other RadioButtons) and editing list which is not correlated to any other code so far

Yes! The answer is: Make sure that this list is not null and that you remembered to initialize it!

No null exception, no any other message just 'strange' difference in xaml and no action in running app.

Sorry everyone :)